# Make DIV visible if another DIV is currently visible and contains a valid value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Little hard to explain this in the subject line.

I currently have a number of DIV's that are mandatory set to invisible and only set to visible if a member of a group. 1 DIV however ("dv_RSB16_Category") is set to false unless the DDL ("ddl_RSB16_Brand") within DIV before it ("dv_RSB16_Brand") has a value not equal to 0.

When doing the databind into the fields I don't want "dv_RSB16_Category" to set visible if the data bound to "ddl_RSB16_Brand" is not equal to 0 and "dv_RSB16_Brand" is set to invisible still.

I tried something like this after the databind but it's showing as erroneous:

```
if (ddl_RSB16_Brand.SelectedItem.Value != "0" && dv_RSB16_Brand.Visible = true)
```

Comment: when posting it would help to give the error next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use *equality comparison operator* `==` instead of `=` *assignment* operator in condition for comparing dv_RSB16_Brand.Visible with boolean `true`.

*Change*

```
if (ddl_RSB16_Brand.SelectedItem.Value != "0" && dv_RSB16_Brand.Visible = true)
```

*To*

```
if (ddl_RSB16_Brand.SelectedItem.Value != "0" && dv_RSB16_Brand.Visible == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not manage the display state on your page using JQuery opposed to creating logical rules in the code-behind?

Perhaps create a display model then which handles multiple view scenarios for example...